# UsageStats method for total foreground time problems

Tags: java, android, usagestatsmanager

yesterday i was playing a little with the UsageStatsManager in andorid studio to see how much time i waste on social media using queryUsageStats and then the method getTotalTimeInForeground; i noticed that if i lock my phone while i'm on some apps the time keeps rising so does this means that even if the screen is locked the app is still considered in foreground?
Does anyone knows how to extract the real time in foreground for each app ?Or how to get some data about locked/unlocked time of android devices?

Comment: Have you found a solution?